XamarinForms background color
For a long time I have been trying to change the color of the background, but not the background of the application itself, but the background that is located behind the clock and the battery charge. Is it possible to change this, and if so, how?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VictoryVerona.Views"
       Title="VictoryVerona"
       Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
       
       x:Class="VictoryVerona.AppShell">

    <!--
        The overall app visual hierarchy is defined here, along with navigation.
    
        https://docs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/
    -->

    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="Black"/>
                
            </Style>
            
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>

    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Browse" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Browse" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Browse" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Browse" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </TabBar>

    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
    </TabBar>


</Shell>


This is my own example the blue background is underlined
Normal black background

Update
I actually dinf it, if u would like to change the color of status bar u need to go your project NAME.Android then Resources -> values -> styles.sml
Then uncomment  #000000 and change here the color!
